# CRM 2011 plugin with no code returns "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I wrote a plugin to update some data on a salesorder, right after the user has updated the record itself. Based on whether certain dates were changed, I want to update another field with a formatted date.

I ran across the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary" so I added a few traces to see where it exactly returned the error. I then discovered that the trace never wrote out, so I assumed the code I wrote never gets executed. This is indeed the case because if I just do

```csh
public class SalesOrderPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

    }
}
```

I get the same error:

```xml
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1
    [[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:
    Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Iu.PreConsultants.Crm.SalesOrderPlugin: 
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.Detail:
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
    <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Iu.PreConsultants.Crm.SalesOrderPlugin: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2012-02-21T07:09:48.471378Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText>

        [Iu.PreConsultants.Crm: Iu.PreConsultants.Crm.SalesOrderPlugin]
        [1486b5df-595c-e111-b7b0-46c950e6c8cd: Iu.PreConsultants.Crm.SalesOrderPlugin: Update of salesorder]


    </TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

The settings for the plugin:

- Post-validation
- Synchronous execution mode
- Server deployment

On a hosted setup (sandboxed)

SalesOrder has been altered and has some custom attributes.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Vincent

Comment: Can you amend the body of that plugin to throw an exception by way of a test? Just add: throw new ApplicationException("Hello, Exception!");. Throwing an exception will display that specific error message. Based on your description and the error message given, I suspect CRM is executing an older version of your plugin library.

Comment: Indeed, I tried this and it still returns the same exception. I also added at the start some trace info, then threw an exception, but this wasn't working either... I think it throws the exception even before the plugin gets executed, is this possible?

Comment: @VincentvanEderen: I don't think it is possible.  glosrob is probably right.  CRM might be executing an older version that throws an exception.  You should try to recompile and redeploy your empty plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it works now. It seems like glosrob was right and there was a cached version kept by CRM. I tried to use "Update" on the IPlugin implementations on the registrationtool from the SDK but that wasn't sufficient. I had to Update the Assembly first, and after that, the IPlugin implementations also got updated.

Comment: Yep that mirrors my experience - you have to explicitly update the assembly first and then update the step(s) required. Glad it is sorted!